# Shift/reduce conflict with args and kwargs - PLY

Tags: python, parsing, bnf, ply, shift-reduce-conflict

I'm writing parser for Python-like language, which allows to pass two types of arguments (positional and named) to functions. And, like in Python, named argument must be passed *after* positional.
I wrote a grammar for it, but it has shift/reduce conflicts, and I can't even imagine how to write it another way.

Here's my grammar:

```
optionalcomma : COMMA
              | empty

arguments : posargs
         | posargs COMMA kwargs
         | kwargs
         | empty

posargs : optionalnl languageitem
        | optionalnl languageitem COMMA posargs

kwargs : optionalnl varassign optionalcomma
       | optionalnl varassign COMMA kwargs
```

Here, `optionalnl` is optional newline, `languageitem` is basic object that can be passed as positional argument, and `varassign` is variable assignment rule, which is equal to passing a named argument to function.
The parser goes through arguments to first comma, and doesn't know which item (kwarg or posarg) will follow the comma; that's the problem. And I completely stuck here, can't write the correct grammar.

I'm using LALR(1) parser PLY, so advice to use GLR parsing won't help me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is something unusual in the rest of your grammar, writing `posargs` in the usual left-recursive fashion will not produce a shift/reduce conflict:

```
posargs : optionalnl languageitem
        | posargs ',' optionalnl languageitem
```

Personally, I'd write `kwargs` left-recursively as well.